# What is the best approach to store multiple locators for a single element to be used throughout multiple tests?

Tags: java, selenium

I am testing multiple web applications that are mostly the same, but do not have the same locators for the same element in some cases.

In the first place I was using the `FindBy` annotation in each class and everything was mostly fine.

After that I have decided to create a Java class to store all the locators where I am using the `@FindAll` + `FindBy` annotations and I am creating a List of `WebElements` based on those annotations.

Now I have come across some issues for some of my tests where the `WebDriverWait` would not wait the given time and return `NoSuchElementException` almost instantly.

Is there a better approach on storing locators and using them globally in general and also for my case here?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a better approach on storing locators and using them globally in general and also for my case here?
Yes, Use the Page Factory Model.
What is the page factory model - https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Though we usually call this type of abstraction 'page object', the correct term is 'locator abstraction'. Guru 99 is a great place to start, maybe you can keep the locators that are common in a parent class and have the application specific locators in child classes.

> Blockquote Now I have come across some issues for some of my tests where the WebDriverWait would not wait the given time and return NoSuchElementException almost instantly.

Can you share details on this? Maybe you can consider writing a custom wait condition using a fluent wait or a custom expected condition?